# What does "uniformly" mean in this diffusion process definition?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes

I'm reading *Stochastic Processes and Applications* by Pavliotis, in Ch 2.5 *Diffusion Processes and the Forward and Backward Kolmogorov Equations*, it defines ***diffusion process*** as:

> A Markov process $X_t$ in $\mathbb R$ with transition function
> $P(\Gamma, t | x,s)$ is called a *diffusion process* if the following
> conditions are satisfied.
>
> 1. (Continuity). For every $x$ and every $\varepsilon>0$,
>    $$\int_{|x-y|>\varepsilon}  P(dy, t | x,s) = o(t-s)$$
>    **uniformly** over $s<t$.
> 2. (Definition of drift coefficient). There exists a function $b(x,s)$ such that for every $x$ and every $\varepsilon>0$,
>    $$\int_{|y-x|\le\varepsilon} (y-x) P(dy, t | x,s) = b(x,s)(t-s) + o(t-s)$$
>    **uniformly** over $s<t$.
> 3. (Definition of diffusion coefficient). There exists a function $\Sigma(x,s)$ such that for every $x$ and every $\varepsilon>0$,
>    $$\int_{|y-x|\le\varepsilon} (y-x)^2 P(dy, t | x,s) = \Sigma(x,s)(t-s) + o(t-s)$$
>    **uniformly** over $s<t$.

I don't quite get the meaning of the **uniformly** here. For example, in the first condition of Continuity, what does the *uniformly* mean?

My understanding of uniformly is more on calculus, regarding to a family of functions. For example, in [Uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) the definition is

> Suppose $E$ is a set and ${(f_n)}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of
> real-valued functions on it. We say the sequence
> $({f_n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is uniformly convergent on $E$ with limit
> $f:E\to \mathbb R$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number
> $N$ such
> that for all $n\geq N$ and $x \in E$, $ |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

But in the above diffusion process definition there is no family of functions, so what does the *uniformly* mean?